# how to figure out if google invisible reCapthca protects my website against bots?

Tags: testing, laravel-5, invisible-recaptcha

I've used google invisible reCaptcha for my register form , how can I test reCaptcha against bots without implementing a bot to test it?

my web framework is laravel 5.3 .

Answer (score 0):

one way that I found accidentally is changing your IP.